# Canvas positioning not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to draw a frame using `HTML canvas`. here's my code:
here, 500px will be my image height-width. SO, I'm trying to draw a frame around the image...

```js
function myCanvas() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var top = document.getElementById("top");
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
    var left = document.getElementById("left");
    var right = document.getElementById("right");
//    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);


    var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(left, 'repeat'); 
    var topPtrn = ctx.createPattern(top, 'repeat'); 
    var bottomPtrn = ctx.createPattern(bottom, 'repeat'); 
    var rightPtrn = ctx.createPattern(right, 'repeat'); 

    ctx.fillStyle = ptrn; // left
    ctx.fillRect(0, top.clientHeight, left.clientWidth, 500); // left


    ctx.fillStyle = topPtrn; // top
    ctx.fillRect(left.clientWidth, 0, 500, top.clientHeight); // top


    ctx.fillStyle = bottomPtrn; // bottom
    ctx.fillRect(left.clientWidth, 500 + top.clientHeight, 500, bottom.clientHeight); // botttom

    //ctx.save();
    //ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);

    //ctx.restore();
    ctx.fillStyle = rightPtrn;
    ctx.fillRect(500 + left.clientWidth, top.clientHeight, right.clientWidth, 500); // right    
   // ctx.rotate(180*Math.PI/180);


}
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="top" src="https://i.imgur.com/jbOpU7Y.png" alt="The Scream" >

<img id="bottom" src="https://i.imgur.com/ftckhxk.png" alt="The Scream" >

<img id="left" src="https://i.imgur.com/PNahWhN.png" alt="The Scream" >

<img id="right" src="https://i.imgur.com/7lWBQcp.png" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas to fill:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<p><button onclick="myCanvas()">Try it</button></p>
```

The top and the left patterns are working correctly but the right and bottom patterns are not showing correctly.

Update: My goal is to poisiton 4 images such a way that it looks like a frame. Left and top images are positioned fine. But right and bottom images are positioned correctly but showing incorrectly. Run it on code snippet to understand what i meant

Comment: "Not working" and "not showing correctly" are not technical terms. Define what you mean by both.

Comment: @Ahsan Aasim check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use canvas height and width to such operations:

```
ctx.fillRect(0, top.clientHeight, left.clientWidth, c.height-(2*top.clientHeight)); // left
ctx.fillRect(left.clientWidth, 0, c.width-(2*top.clientWidth), top.clientHeight); // top
ctx.fillRect(left.clientWidth, c.height-top.clientHeight, c.width-(2*bottom.clientWidth), bottom.clientHeight); // botttom
ctx.fillRect(c.width-right.clientWidth, top.clientHeight, right.clientWidth, c.height-(2*top.clientHeight)); // right
```

Comment: Okay i successfully drew the frame around the image. but for pattern image height is not working. Image is getting cut under the fillrect height. Can you please check my other question here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987196/setting-height-to-image-for-canvas-drawing

Comment: Please notice that you have images in different sizes. I pressumed that is a draft, and in your real solution, you would like to have images in the same size. If you use the same size, you have your solution. If my solution is now fine for you, pleas check it as correct answer, then I'll check your other question.

Comment: okay as the question was about positioning, so the above code works perfectly. But i need to resize the image to fit it inside the drawn rect. check my question here pls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987196/setting-height-to-image-for-canvas-drawing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the pattern will fill the entire context from `0,0` til `maxWidth, maxHeight` and by filling a rect at `x,y` of `w x h` is like masking everything else but that surface and the pattern doesn't start from the `0,0` relative to that surface.

So you need to change the origin of the canvas context for `bottom` and `right` borders.

```js
function myCanvas() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var top = document.getElementById("top");
  var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
  var left = document.getElementById("left");
  var right = document.getElementById("right");
  //    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);


  var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(left, 'repeat');
  var topPtrn = ctx.createPattern(top, 'repeat');
  var bottomPtrn = ctx.createPattern(bottom, 'repeat');
  var rightPtrn = ctx.createPattern(right, 'repeat');

  ctx.fillStyle = ptrn; // left
  ctx.fillRect(0, top.clientHeight, left.clientWidth, 500); // left


  ctx.fillStyle = topPtrn; // top
  ctx.fillRect(left.clientWidth, 0, 500, top.clientHeight); // top

  ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, left.clientWidth, 500 + top.clientHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = bottomPtrn; // bottom
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, bottom.clientHeight); // botttom

  ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, -left.clientWidth, -500 - top.clientHeight);
  ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, left.clientWidth + 500, top.clientHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = rightPtrn;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, right.clientWidth, 500); // right    



}
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="top" src="https://i.imgur.com/jbOpU7Y.png" alt="The Scream">

<img id="bottom" src="https://i.imgur.com/ftckhxk.png" alt="The Scream">

<img id="left" src="https://i.imgur.com/PNahWhN.png" alt="The Scream">

<img id="right" src="https://i.imgur.com/7lWBQcp.png" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas to fill:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<p><button onclick="myCanvas()">Try it</button></p>
```

Comment: Okay i successfully drew the frame around the image. but for pattern image height is not working. Image is getting cut under the fillrect height. Can you please check my other question here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987196/setting-height-to-image-for-canvas-drawing

Comment: @AhsanAasimwas this answer helpful for you?

Comment: yes it was helpful but enk1s answer works nicely. i managed to draw image around the image but my image is not showing up correctly. You can see my other question